# Integral of probit likelihood

Tags: panel-data, probit, integral, numerics

I'm currently trying to implement the Heckman method for estimating the dynamic probit panel model (Original paper can be found [here](https://eml.berkeley.edu/~mcfadden/discrete/ch4.pdf)). I'm trying to implement it according a paper of [Stewart (2006)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9b9a/64fc7afa016b95140b237c700c08f370c476.pdf), with the following Likelihood:

$\prod_{i}\int_{\alpha^*}\{\Phi[(z'_{i,1}\pi+\theta\sigma_{\alpha}\alpha^*)(2y_{i,1}-1)]\prod_{t=2}^{T}\Phi[(\gamma y_{i,t-1}+x'_{i,t}\beta+\sigma_{\alpha}\alpha^*)(2y_{i,t}-1)]\}dF(\alpha^*)$

with $\alpha^*=\dfrac{\alpha}{\sigma_{\alpha}}$. My intuition here was to find the loglikelihood, which gets me:

$\sum_i[\int_{\alpha^*}\{\Phi[(z'_{i,1}\pi+\theta\sigma_{\alpha}\alpha^*)(2y_{i,1}-1)]\}dF(\alpha^*)+\sum_{t=2}^T\int_{\alpha^*}\{\Phi[(\gamma y_{i,t-1}+x'_{i,t}\beta+\sigma_{\alpha}\alpha^*)(2y_{i,t}-1)]\}]dF(\alpha^*)$

and integrate the separate parts. Now according to Stewart I can integrate this function by applying the gaussian hermite quadrature in accordance with [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1912613.pdf) (Butler/Moffit 1982). And here is my main issue. As I'm just a mere economist, I don't really understand how to do this correctly.

**Question: How can I correctly integrate the loglikelihood over $F(\alpha^*)$ ? To clarify: I'm not sure how to apply the solution proposed in the Butler/Boffit paper, hence not sure how to apply the quadrature in my case. **

Comment: I am suspect whether a closed form solution is necessary or possible. You allude to hermite quadrature as a numerical solution. Is that not a desired workaround?

Comment: Maybe I haven't made myself clear. Yes, of course the quadrature is a desired workaround, but I don't really know how to properly use it and paper I've liniked to wasn't really helpful in that regard, neither were the basic textbooks.